# OCL: navigating unidirectional associations against the arrowhead direction

Tags: eclipse, uml, emf, ocl, ecore

I read here https://wiki.eclipse.org/OCL/FAQ that

> **How do I access unnavigable opposites in Ecore**
>
> In UML, an association that is intended only to be navigated in one
>   direction at run-time may be drawn with a unidirectional arrow.
>
> OCL evaluation occurs at analysis-time and may navigate in both
>   directions regardless of the arrows.

Is this part of the OCL standard or only an eclipse ecore thing?

An example: Given two classes A and B, and a uni-directional association from A to B (but not from B to A). In a class diagram, this could be illustrated with an arrow from A to B (a line with one arrowhead pointing to B).

Is it really part of the standard to write OCL constraints that navigate ***against*** this arrow direction?

I could not find anything about this in the OCL spec, see [here](http://www.omg.org/spec/OCL/).

Comment: Not sure about OCL but it seems logical that OCL may navigate both sides. It's meant to validate a model also at design time regardless of what constraints may apply on implementation level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The navigability indication in UML is not absolute, but merely an indicator of how you can easily navigate.

From the UML 2.5 specs

> Navigability means that instances participating in links at runtime
>   (instances of an Association) can be accessed efficiently from
>   instances at the other ends of the Association. The precise mechanism
>   by which such efficient access is achieved is implementation specific.
>   If an end is not navigable, access from the other ends **may or may not
>   be possible**, and if it is, it might not be efficient.

So therefore I guess OCL should be able to navigate in both ways, regardless of the navigability.